# Assembler code in C++ code

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, g++, inline-assembly

How can I put Intel asm code into my c++ application?
I'm using Dev-C++.

I want to do sth like that:

```
int temp = 0;
int usernb = 3;

pusha
mov eax, temp
inc eax
xor usernb, usernb
mov eax, usernb
popa
```

This is only example.
How can I do sth like that?

**UPDATE:
How does it look in Visual Studio ?**

Comment: DevC++ is not a compiler. It ships with an **extremely old** and **extremely bad** copy of MinGW 3.x. You should probably get a recent MinGW build and use that manually instead. Note that any embedded asm is going to be compiler specific. (And it's recommended you really don't do it because compilers produce better ASM than most people produce nowadays)

Comment: @Everyone: [`Bloodshed Dev-C++ is a full-featured Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for the C/C++ programming language. It uses Mingw port of GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) as it's compiler. Dev-C++ can also be used in combination with Cygwin or any other GCC based compiler`](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html)

Comment: @Sehe: I believe that's what I said. :)

Comment: @Billy: that only proves that we both thought there was something to be pointed out. For the record, the SO web interface is wide open to race conditions that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UPDATE: How does it look in Visual Studio ?

If you are building for 64 bit, you cannot use inline assembly in Visual Studio. If you are building for 32 bit, then you use [`__asm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz.aspx) to do the embedding.

Generally, using inline ASM is a bad idea.

1. You're probably going to produce worse ASM than a compiler.
2. Using any ASM in a method generally defeats any optimizations which try to touch that method (i.e. inlining).
3. If you need to access specific features of the processor not obvious in C++ (e.g. SIMD instructions) then you can use much more consistent with the language *intrinsics* provided by most any compiler vendor. Intrinsics give you all the speed of that "special" instruction but in a way which is compatible with the language semantics *and* with optimizers.

Comment: This answer is technically correct but not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a complete howto here http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     int temp = 0;
     int usernb = 3;

     __asm__ volatile (
          "pusha \n"
          "mov eax, %0 \n"
          "inc eax \n"
          "mov ecx, %1 \n"
          "xor ecx, %1 \n"
          "mov %1, ecx \n"
          "mov eax, %1 \n"
          "popa \n"
          : // no output
          : "m" (temp), "m" (usernb) ); // input
     exit(0);
}
```

After that you need to compile with something like:

```
gcc -m32 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -masm=intel -o casm casmt.c && ./casm && echo $?
output:
0
```

You need to compile with the -masm=intel flag since you want intel assembly syntax :)

Comment: Is there a way of writing this that also works on microsoft visual studio c++ compiler?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example to show the syntax for GCC/Dev-C++:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x = 10, y;

    asm ("movl %1, %%eax;"
         "movl %%eax, %0;"
        :"=r"(y)    /* y is output operand */
        :"r"(x)     /* x is input operand */
        :"%eax");   /* %eax is clobbered register */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your compiler. But from your tags I guess you use gcc/g++ then you can use [gcc inline assembler](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html). But the syntax is quite weird and a bit different from intel syntax, although it achieves the same.

**EDIT:** With [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (or the Visual C++ compiler) it get's much easier, as it uses the usual Intel syntax.

Comment: `gcc` and `g++` can also compile intel syntax asm you need need to add the flag `-masm=intel` :)

Comment: Wow, now I didn't know that. Makes gcc inline assembler much more usable to me, as I'm a real enemy of this ugly gcc syntax (even if it might be more powerful). But actually I try to avoid asm anyways, as intrinsics are most times sufficient (for e.g. SSE).

Comment: hehe yeah, I don't like AT&T that much as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

If it's for some exercices I'd recommend some real assembler avoiding inlined code as it can get rather messy/confusing.

Some basics using GCC can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ia/index.html).

If you're open to trying MSVC (not sure if GCC is a requirement), I'd suggest you have a look at MSVC's interpretation which is (in my opinion) a lot easier to read/understand, especially for learning assembler. An example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).